# UITextField display editing when activity stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my application login screen I use text fields to get the login credentials and through API I receive the data. While performing the API call with activity indicator I do end editing from the view controller like

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

I am facing an issue with this, before the API call endEditing works. When response received from API again the keyboard is blinked for 2 seconds

in iOS 10 I am not facing this devices with iOS 11 and above I am facing this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share a video/gif ?

Answer (score 0):

use third party library for activity indicator such as
Visit https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD
They easily handle user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

During API call you can show an activity indicator. That will show on top and not able to access the lower views. [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD) is a good example to do that.

Or

You can just disable user interaction by using this  `[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];` when Return API call then enable user interaction again  `[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`.

Hopefully, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly the flow of your exposed comment, but I deduce some problem here :

*While performing the API call with activity indicator I do end editing
from the view controller like*

Just make sure that you're not setting any property of an object from UIKit on a background thread. All calls to UIKit methods must be on main thread.

Also keep this in mind about *endEditing:* method :

> This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for
>   the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one,
>   it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force
>   parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked; it is
>   forced to resign.

This method have the origin that view hierarchy are correct to find any TextField. As a general rule always do this before call the (supposed asynchronous) login API.

1 - Hide keyboard sending resignFirstResponder() to both textfields or tapping return Key on your keyboard. (check [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield#1652976))

2 - Show the activity indicator.

3 - Make network Request and disable the login button while network request is in progress.

4 - when receive the response if response is in another thread , switch to main thread , stop activity indicator and proceed with the rest of your UI logic.

Hope this help. cheers